# Protocol Doesn't Send Value to Other VC

Tags: swift, protocols, parent

That is my footerView called FooterTableViewCell. I have this protocol called SurveyAnswerTableViewCellDelegate. It's parent is AddQuestionViewController.

When I tap on the footerView I trigger @IBActtion.

```
@objc protocol SurveyAnswerTableViewCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func textSaved(_ text: String)
}

class FooterTableViewCell: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
var parentVC: AddQuestionViewController!

@IBAction func addNewTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("tapped")
        let newTag = model.tag + 1
        parentVC.addNewAnswer()
    }
```

This button action triggers AddQuestionViewController

```
class AddQuestionViewController: SurveyAnswerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, SurveyAnswerTableViewCellDelegate {
    var answers: [SurveyAnswerModel] = []
    var savedText : String = ""
    static var delegate: SurveyAnswerTableViewCellDelegate?
```

I try creating an empty string and append a new answer to my array. But this text here is always "".

```
func addNewAnswer() {
        let newAnswer = SurveyAnswerModel(answer: savedText, tag: 0)
        self.answers.append(newAnswer)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func textSaved(_ text: String) {
         savedText = text
    }
```

The textfield I try to read is inside SurveyAnswerTableViewCell while setting up the cell inside the tableview I call setup function.

```
class SurveyAnswerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    weak var delegate: SurveyAnswerTableViewCellDelegate?
    var parentVC: AddQuestionViewController!

func setup() {
        if let text = self.textField.text {
            self.delegate?.textSaved(textField.text!)
        }
    }

extension AddQuestionViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as SurveyAnswerTableViewCell
        cell.parentVC = self
        cell.setup()
        return cell
    }
```

How can I successfully send that text to AddQuestionViewController so it appends a new answer with correct string

Comment: Where is called `textSaved(_:)`? Your question is unclear since the delegate is static? Where is it set? You pass the `AddQuestionViewController` to the footer view? Not in a `weak`?

Comment: I completed the missing code.

Comment: I think ```self.delegate``` in side ```setup``` function is ```nil```

Comment: "Protocol Doesn't Send Value" -- protocol is a blueprint, it's not capable of sending anything on its own. Also `AddQuestionViewController` is not a parent of the protocol `SurveyAnswerTableViewCellDelegate` (it would be if `SurveyAnswerTableViewCellDelegate` extended it). Also how you set/pass delegate is unclear. In short: please take time to properly understand language basics and implement the delegation pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what it looks like is happening:

1. Button tapped
2. `addNewTapped(_:)` invoked
3. `addNewAnswer()` invoked
4. `newAnswer` is appended to `answers`
5. `tableView.reloadData()` invoked
6. Cells are regenerated with new/empty textfields (so `delegate.textSaved` is never invoked)

so I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but here's what I figure are a couple possible routes:

- store `UITextField`s separately and add them into table cells so they're not removed by a table reload
- conform `AddQuestionViewController` to `UITextFieldDelegate` and set it as the textfields' delegate to observe textfield texts changing (and if you're only using 1 textfield, you could set `savedText` there)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things keeping this from working.

1. You are calling `SurveyAnswerTableViewCell`'s `setup()` function directly after dequeuing the cell for reuse. It has not yet (re)appeared on the screen at that point, so the user has not had a chance to enter anything into the text field.
2. You don't currently set the delegate property of `SurveyAnswerTableViewCell` to anything, so even if the textfield had valid input, the delegate would be `nil` and `delegate?.textSaved(textField.text!)` wouldn't do anything.
3. Both of the previous points mean that the value of `AddQuestionViewController .savedText` never gets updated from the empty string. So when `addNewAnswer()` tries to read it, it will always see that empty string.

Rather than reading the text field when the cell is dequeued, it would make more sense to save the text field value when the user is done typing.

To do that, conform the cell to UITextFieldDelegate and implement the `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)` method. From within that method you can then call the delegate method you already have to save the text. **Make sure the delegate property on the cell has been set by the VC, or else this won't do anything!**

The VC itself should not have a delegate property of type `SurveyAnswerTableViewCellDelegate`. It serves *as* the delegate, rather than *having* one. If this doesn't quite make sense, I would recommend reviewing some online resources on the delegate pattern.

So make sure the ViewController conforms to `SurveyAnswerTableViewCellDelegate` and then set the cell's delegate value to the VC. The cellForRowAt function should then look something like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as SurveyAnswerTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

As a side note, neither the footer nor the cell should have a reference to the parent view controller. as a general rule it is good to avoid subviews being aware of their parent views. Things get unnecessarily complicated when there is two-way knowledge sharing between components, and it makes the subview much less reusable. I would recommend making a delegate for the footer as well, and removing the `parentVC` property from both the footer and the cell.